# Adding persistent route through PowerShell not working for Windows 10 Pro VPN client

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell, routing

I'm setting up a new VPN server using L2TP and I'm hitting my last snag.

I'm now able to connect to the L2TP VPN using the native Windows 10 Pro client. I do not want to use the remote gateway for internet traffic, only when I'm accessing workstations/servers on the remote LAN.  I have `use default gateway of remote network` unchecked in advanced options.

Relevant info:

- Local network: 192.168.0.1
- VPN network: 10.8.0.1
- Remote LAN: 192.168.1.1

Once connected to the VPN, if I open a command prompt and type `netsh interface ipv4 add route 192.168.1.0/24 "Tom"` it works as expected.  I am now able to access remote workstations/servers on the LAN.

I removed the `netsh` rule as I want it to be persistent. I disconnected from the VPN. I reconnected to the VPN. Then I went to PowerShell and typed `Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "Tom" -DestinationPrefix 192.168.1.0/24`.

This command replies successfully but it does *not* allow me to access the remote machines. The pings come back unresponsive. If I once again add the `netsh` route manually, it works great.

Can someone please assist me in adding this route so it is persistent even after disconnecting the VPN or rebooting my local machine?

Comment: `New-NetRoute` instead of `Add-VpnConnectionRoute`?

Answer (score 0):

ScottPacker: in the end of the command, add `-PassThru`, and after that, you ran the powershell command you have disconnect/connect again to work.

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "YourVPN" -DestinationPrefix "192.168.1.0/24" -PassThru
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnectionroute?view=windowsserver2022-ps, `-PassThru` is just to return an object as an output from that command.
It doesn't affect how the settings in any way.