# How can I force all the traffic to a particular domain to go over VPN connection

Tags: windows-10, vpn, split-tunnel

I use a split tunnel VPN from work. This VPN shows up in Setting --> VPN.

I want to force the traffic to a particular domain to always go over VPN. How can I do that?

Comment: A very similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1344916/adding-persistent-route-through-powershell-not-working-for-windows-10-pro-vpn-cl

Comment: If by domain you mean domain name, you likely cant. VPNs work by routing IP addresses - so you need to find out the IP addresses associated with the domain. You can then route this IPs through the VPN.

Comment: @davidgo how can I do that?

Comment: That is unansweable without knowledge of the domain. In the simplest case you resolve the appropriate domain/subdomain to an IP address. More complex scenarios involve you reaching out to the owner of the domain and get the IP address ranges from them.